# A surface of revolution like metric

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

For the metric

$du^2+f(u)^2dv^2$

with $|f'(u)|\le 1$ this is the surface of revolution:

$(f(u)\cos v, f(u)\sin v, \int\sqrt{1-f'(u)^2} du)$.

My question is now for the metric

$du^2+g(u)^2dv^2$

with $g'(u)>1$ is there any way to embed into $\mathbb{R}^3$? If not how do you see it is impossible?

Comment: Why the $\lt 0 $ inside radical sign?

Comment: Yeah, that is the problem. The embedding I gave is only good for $|f'(u)|\le 1$. I want to know if there is some different way to do or think about what happens to the surface it if you have $|f'(u)|>1$.

Comment: It is not defined there. With positive sign you are plotting z coordinate equal to arc length

Comment: Yes, I understand the map I have here isn't defined for $|f'(u)|>1$ but it isn't clear to me that there doesn't exist some other embedding in the case $|f'(u)|>1$...

Answer (score 2):

If $f'(u) > 1$, the metric
$$
du^{2} + f(u)^{2}\, dv^{2}
\tag{1}
$$
does not embed into Euclidean $3$-space *as a surface of rotation*, effectively because your formula for embedding (1) as a surface of rotation is general, and the third coordinate ceases to be real if $f'(u) > 1$.

Geometrically, think of measuring arc length along a meridian (a.k.a., a generator or profile) and asking how much area per unit length the surface has: For a surface of rotation, the maximum occurs when the surface profile is a line perpendicular to the axis of rotation, which (if you check) corresponds to $f'(u) = 1$. (More details can be found, for example, in [*A Symplectic Look at Surfaces of Rotation*](http://dx.doi.org/10.5169/seals-66685), l'Ens. Math **49** (2003) 157-172.)

If $f'(u) > 1$, the resulting metric *may* embed in Euclidean $3$-space: Think of $f(u) = mu$ for $m > 1$, which embeds as a "saddle cone". Though I don't have a proof, I expect it's difficult to decide in general whether or not (1) embeds globally (isometrically) into Euclidean $3$-space.

Answer (score 2):

In general, one cannot do this globally. Notice that the case $f(u)= \cosh u$ corresponds to hyperbolic space and, by Hilbert theorem, this space cannot be regarded as a surface of Euclidean 3-space. (However, locally, hyperobolic space can be regarded as the surface of revolution generated by the tractrix.)